# Why are my Vue custom directives not working?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuejs3

I'm new with Vue and even newer with custom directives, I'm trying something basic, but it's just not working and I would like to know what's wrong, thank u!
I have these two directives:
one in main.ts:

```
app.directive('display', {
  beforeMount: (el, binding) => {
    el.style.display = binding.value
  }
})
```

one in App.vue:

```
app.directive('color', {
      beforeMount: el => {
        el.style.color = 'red'
      }
    })
```

Here I'm trying to use it but nothing happens:

```
    <h1
      class="text-4xl font-semibold my-10 text-center capitalize text-black dark:text-white"
      v-display:none
      v-color
    >
```

If i hace to register them I don't know how, just trying i did this inside the  of the Component FAQ ( the one I'm imp the directives ):

```
  directives: {
    color: {

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your custom directive definition might be correct, but wrong usage. Try using it like below:

```html
<h1 
  class="..."
  v-display="`none`"
  v-color
>
```

The reason why you would wrap the word `none` in `` or '' is because if you just write `v-display="none"`, Vue looks for a variable with the name `none`. Since there is no such variable, it returns `undefined`. When you write `v-display="'none'"`, it passes a string `none`, hence, Vue can work it out.

I think `v-color` should work as intended. I made a [working example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNptUbtuwzAM/BVWixMglpE1dQIU7dClcxcNSWw6USCJgiS7CAz/e+k8jAI1oEHUnY68Yy/evJddi2IjylgF7RNETK3fKaetp5Cgh4ANDNAEspAxNVMOQLmKXEzQvZOhAFvox9cjNhTwi1qXFmiW90cANDKmq0FZjeStEgFrJV5HcFCOz6T2oaM3h+u83gqO2tXanf4L19O/B0V2B9PiTAsbT8xiS4vsE40h+KZg6pdsqVxZ3BNg71wktCyZkCuA8ryGLr+Nv+v7m8gwlMV5/Qd9zMD29o4c7pWYo2rnWzaaW6rRMJdxJo7Np4ZiJe7Z5/bg5SWS4+3cHKsHEJXYPDNQgncy1kqcU/JxUxSxqcadXqKkcCr4JgMnqC1KjDY/BvqJGFhYiWc+YvgF7AGzXw==) if you want to refer to that as well.

Comment: Regular `'` (single quote) are also fine, it's not mandatory to use backticks.